# How to make a invisible clickable button

Tags: html, web-deployment

```
<!-- Log out Button -->
            <form class="btn dento-btn booking-btn" method = "POST" action = "home.html"> {%csrf_token%} <button type="submit" > Logout</button> Logout</form> 


            <a href="{% url 'login' %}" class="btn dento-btn booking-btn">LOG OUT</a>
```

[image]

How do I convert the 1st button type to the 2nd button type. From the image i am trying to convert my left log out button to my right logout button.

so that it execute the logout {%csrf_token%} on the right log out button.

I tried to make the button hidden from the form but it will not be clickable.

Comment: Why not styling the existing button?

Comment: Also: a form is not a "button." A form is used to collect user data and typically requires a "submit" action.  "Logging out" usually does not require a form element.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do it is:

In your html:

```html
<button type="submit" class="invisible-button">Logout</button>
```

In your CSS:

```css
.invisible-button {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the code as it is, check out Zakk´s solution.
Otherwise you could also just remove the `Logout` from the form (Not the one in the button) and apply all the styles you have for your form to your button.

Answer (score 0):

another possible way

```css
.invisible-button{
  visibility: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="invisible-button">Logout</button>
```